# Tweepy / StreamListener

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm learning about data scraping in python using tweepy and I ran on a syntax error with my code. I think I'm missing something, but it looks fine to me? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
twitterStream = Stream(auth, MyStreamListener('COVID', 'COVID-19', 'COVID19', 'NCR', 'Manila', 'Metro Manila', 'Coronavirus', 'Cases'))

twitterStream.filter(track=['COVID', 'COVID-19', 'COVID19', 'NCR', 'Manila', 'Metro Manila', 'Coronavirus', 'Cases'], async=True)
```

The last line of the code is where I'm getting the error.

Here's a link to view the whole code: https://paste.ofcode.org/?edit=bvg8wTJsTymfJhLgaytktD

Comment: In the first line,  shouldn't the topics be a list? They look duplicative so define as a variable first and use it wherever appropriate.

Comment: @EricTruett made it into a list, but the syntax error still persist though

Answer (score 0):

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import StreamListener


auth = OAuthHandler(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(config.ACCESS_TOKEN, config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

listener = StreamListener(api)

stream = Stream(auth, listener)

stream.filter(track=['COVID', 'COVID-19', 'COVID19', 'NCR', 'Manila', 'Metro Manila', 'Coronavirus', 'Cases'], async=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI that in Tweepy4.0.0 StreamListner merged with Stream.

You can import it now directly via:

```
from tweepy import Stream
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338089/cant-import-streamlistener)