# Can't import StreamListener

Tags: python, api, twitter, import, tweepy

I'm trying to create a data stream in Python using the Twitter API, but I'm unable to import the `StreamListener` correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):
 
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
 
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
 
twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#python'])
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 6, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
ImportError: cannot import name 'StreamListener' from 'tweepy.streaming' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) was released yesterday and it merged `StreamListener` into `Stream`.

I recommend updating your code to subclass [`Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/stream.html) instead.
Alternatively, you can downgrade to v3.10.0.

Answer (score 6):

For `Tweepy v4`, you don't need to use `StreamListener`. The following is an edited code for v4:

```
import tweepy

class MyListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
 
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
 
twitter_stream = MyListener(
  "Consumer Key here", "Consumer Secret here",
  "Access Token here", "Access Token Secret here"
)
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#python'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak will fix this

```
#from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener #OLD CODE

import tweepy # NEW CODE

#class TweetListener (StreamListener): #OLD CODE

class TweetListener (tweepy.Stream): # NEW CODE
```